# Ponteiro de Ponteiro

Tags: c

Boa tarde, estou tentando resolver um exercício de uma matéria da faculdade, contudo não estou sabendo manipular corretamente o uso de ponteiros, segue a baixo o enunciado e o código.

> Vimos que alterar o RA de a1 não altera o RA do aluno em c.
>
> Isso acontece pois c não tem a1 na sua lista de alunos. A classe c tem
>   uma cópia de a1 em sua lista.
>
> Suponha que queiramos que a mudança em a1 causasse uma mudança em c.
>   Para isso, a lista de alunos em c, não deve conter alunos, mas
>   ponteiros para alunos.
>
> Mude o campo  aluno *alunos  em c para   aluno **alunos. Agora alunos
>   representa uma lista para *aluno.
>
> Modifique o resto do código de modo que a alteração em a1 cause
>   alteração em c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct aluno_s {
  int RA; 
  int CPF;
} aluno;

typedef struct classe_s {
  int n; //quantidade de alunos
  aluno *alunos;
} classe;

void imprime(classe c) {
  for(int i=0; i<c.n; i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", c.alunos[i].RA, c.alunos[i].CPF);
  }
}
void adiciona(aluno a, classe *c) {
  c->alunos[c->n] = a;
  c->n++;
}

int main(void) {
  aluno a1 = {123, 456};
  aluno a2 = {789, 101};
  classe c = {0};
  c.alunos = malloc(sizeof(aluno)*100);

  adiciona(a1, &c);
  adiciona(a2, &c);
  imprime(c);

  a1.RA = 999;

  imprime(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Sáida

```
123 456
789 101
123 456
789 101
```

No exercito eu devo alterar a linha de código

```
aluno *alunos
```

para

```
aluno **alunos
```

e depois disso fazer as alterações necessárias para fazer o código funcionar, contudo quando faço isso e ajusto o código ele está me retornando os endereços de memoria.
Abaixo segue-se o meu código alterado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct aluno_s {
  int RA; 
  int CPF;
} aluno;

typedef struct classe_s {
  int n; //quantidade de alunos
  aluno **alunos;
} classe;

void imprime(classe *c) {
  for(int i=0; i<c->n; i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", c->alunos[i]->RA, c->alunos[i]->CPF);
  }
}
void adiciona(aluno a, classe *c) {
  c->alunos[c->n] = &a;
  c->n++;
}

int main(void) {
  aluno a1 = {123, 456};
  aluno a2 = {789, 101};
  classe c = {0};
  c.alunos = malloc(sizeof(aluno)*100);

  adiciona(a1, &c);
  adiciona(a2, &c);
  imprime(&c);

  a1.RA = 999;

  imprime(&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Saída

```
-1761299816 32765
-1761299816 32765
-1761299816 32765
-1761299816 32765
```

Saída que eu quero

```
123 456
789 101
999 456
789 101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está passando o aluno por cópia,

```
void adiciona(aluno a, classe *c) 
{
    c->alunos[c->n] = &a;
    c->n++;
}
```

assim uma cópia dele é adicionada a `alunos` mas ao sair do escopo da função `adiciona` essa cópia morre e `alunos` aponta para um lixo de memória.

basta passar uma referência ou ponteiro do aluno que está no main

```
void adiciona(aluno *a, classe *c) 
{
    c->alunos[c->n] = a;
    c->n++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Penachia, tenho uma certa dificuldade para entender ponteiros, mas a sua resposta foi bem clara e direta.
PS: Funcionou!!!